# Postgres table inheritance: move from parent to child and vice versa

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, parent-child

I am wondering how I can easily move data between a parent table and its child table in PostgreSQL (9.4) and vice versa.

Assume that I have the following database sample set up:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS director CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE employee(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
employment_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
);

CREATE TABLE director(
director_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
secretary_id INT4 REFERENCES employee(id),
extra_legal_benefits VARCHAR(255) ARRAY
) inherits (employee);

INSERT INTO employee(name, surname)
VALUES ('Alice', 'Alisson');

INSERT INTO employee(name, surname)
VALUES ('Bob', 'Bobson');

INSERT INTO employee(name, surname)
VALUES ('Carol', 'Clarckson');

INSERT INTO director(name, surname, secretary_id, extra_legal_benefits)
VALUES ('David', 'Davidson', 1, '{car, travel expenses}');
```

How can I promote (move) one of the employees to the director table (must no longer appear in the parent)?

How can I demote (move) one of the directors back to the employees table (must no longer apear in the child)?

Comment: `VARCHAR(255)`-  are you aware that the limit of 255 has no special meaning, hidden optimization or some magic performance advantage compared to a value of e.g. 376 or 52957?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Promote an employee:

```
with deleted as (
  delete from only employee 
  where name = 'Carol'
  returning *
)
insert into director (name, surname, secretary_id, extra_legal_benefits)
select name, surname, null, '{flight}'
from deleted;
```

However:

> *must no longer appear in the parent*

Any row in the child table is by definition available in the parent table. You can only "hide" those rows if you use the predicate `only` when selecting from the employee table:

```
select *
from only employee;
```

The above will not show employees that are also director. A plain `select * from employee` however *will* show all names (but you can't distinguish them - that's the nature of inheritance).

---

Demote a director:

```
with deleted as (
  delete from only director 
  where name = 'David'
  returning *
)
insert into employee (name, surname)
select name, surname
from deleted;
```

---

But to be honest, I'd probably model this through an additional column (like `position` or `role`) on the employee entity instead of using inheritance. Or even a many-to-many relationship to a `position` (or `role`) entity as it is not uncommon that employees have multiple roles, e.g. in different departments, teams or other contexts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your accurate and detailed answer. I totally agree with your comment that this could have been modeled alternatively in a real production database. However as a sample, it suits perfectly to understand and explain the inheritance question I had.

Comment: Will postgresql tolerate keeping an id column such as `id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` using this delete-insert construct?

Comment: @retorquere By default, child tables don't inherit constraints.  If, however, you specifically added the same pk sequence and constraint to the child table, you will get a unique constraint violation.

Comment: @deinspanjer so if I understand correctly, any constraints I want to have apply to both the parent and child table I'd have to implement in both?

Comment: @retorquere Yes. Read the pg docs on table inheritance. Constraints don't inherit.  That means if the parent table has a declaration of `id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`, you could insert id = 1 in the parent and then id = 1 in the child because the child's id column will just be a plain INT generated by the sequence with no constraint.  To get the constraint, after creating the child table, `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX child_uidx ON child(id);` and `ALTER TABLE child ADD PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX child_uidx;`  Of course, then you will get that violation I mentioned if you try the code in the answer above.

Comment: I needed to do this `with deleted insert` operation, but I had the id field declared as a primary key in both tables.  I worked around the unique constraint violation by multiplying the id column by 10000 to put the numbers outside the largest value in my table, then after the insert, divided them by 10000 again to put them back to their original values.  Hacky but it worked. Maybe a better hack would have been to multiply by -1...

Comment: @deinspanjer I've toyed around with this and while technically the constraints may not be inherited, it looks like the constraints are still enforced. Looking at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb03401c252c21cdb8a0c3f12d67fd08, the updates on both lines 23 and 25 fail because they hit the constraint on the "other" table.

Comment: Is it possible to the `-1` trick within a single operation? I can see the delete/insert generating new IDs could spell trouble when at some point I'd have FKs pointing into the parent table.